# Breakpoint not hit in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to use the domain name in my routes file and managed to find a useful link to do so.  However, I am unable to debug and set breakpoints in the Global.asax.cs as they are not being hit.

I am using Web Developer 2010 Express and also SQL Server Express on the server.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment yet, but are you hosting with IIS or Visual Studio Development Server? You might have some luck using the [Debugger.Break()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) method if you aren't able to attach the debugger to the hosting process before the application moves past the part of the code you'd like to debug.

For example:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();    
    ...app startup code here...
}
```

Then once you attach your debugger you should be able to move past the break point as you would normally.

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat.  I did try it before but put it in my RegisterRoutes function.